# Certificate chain mantainance

Tags: certificates, x.509, validation

According to standard [rfc5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) , when user wants to validate a certificate, one step is to build a certificate chain, then check whether it is complete. I understand the idea to make a list to implement this requirement as the RFC 5280 stated. Meanwhile, I'm wondering is there any published library available to build a certificate chain if I just throw all certificates to it?

Comment: openssl is doing this for you as do other TLS libraries. Of course you have to use the correct API when "throwing" the certificates into it, which is off-topic here.

Comment: OK. hmm, I meant on server side. For example i have a lot certificates including the ones not supposed to be in the chain, the input a end entity certificate, i will validate it.

Comment: Yes, this can also be programmed with openssl. But again: this is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is totally possible. Common Crypto Libs like OpenSSL and Bouncycastle will do exactly that for you. You provide a list of trusted (root) certificates, a list of chain certificates, and you provide them the certificate that you want to check. It will use just those certificates needed between all you provided to chain up to a trusted root and validate the certificate. You may also get the chain if needed, as described here: http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/12/01/x509-certificate-validation-in-java-build-and-verify-chain-and-verify-clr-with-bouncy-castle/

However, since the main topic here is security, not how to use a lib, except you are just doing it to study or by any reason you really want to get the chain (ex for displaying it), just verify using the standard verify methods, do not try to reimplement RFC5280 by yourself. There are many things to get wrong there.